# Passing array from select list to action class

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts, selectlist

I have a dynamically created multiple select list which gets populated from another select list.

```
  <select multiple size=6 width=150 style="width:150px" id="ToLB" name="ToLB" >
  </select>
```

I am saving the values of the select list as

```
  function arraycreated()
            {               
                var x=document.getElementById("ToLB"); 
                var arraylists = new Array();
                for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
                { 
                    arraylists.push(x.options[i].text);
                }   
arraylists.toString();
<% String[] arraylist = request.getParameterValues("arraylists"); %>
```

and even i am setting an hidden input field

```
  <input type="hidden" name="arraylist" value="<%request.getParameterValues("arraylists"); %>" />
```

Have a form where i call array

```
private String[] arraylist;
public String[] getArraylist() {
    return arraylist;
}

public void setArraylist(String[] arraylist) {
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
}
```

And at last call it back in action class

```
String[] arraylist = createForm.getArraylist();
int arraylength = arraylist.length;
System.out.println("Array -->"+ arraylength);
```

But its not passing the array at all.What wrong am i doing .
Thank you ////

Comment: Till now if i write document.write(arraylists) , it displays result but when passed to action class it produce result "Array --> 1" in console for any nos of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like it's missing the ID tag in the html